# Calculating thrust generated from electric engines

Tags: power

I wanted to calculate the amount of thrust generated from the engines. I am using the blade 180 cfx model.

http://www.bladehelis.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=BLH3450#quickSpecs

After some research I have found a way to calculate the thrust using:

T = ( pi D^2 rho P^2)/2 where P is the Power multiplier and can be calculated using: P= prop constant * (rpm/100)^power factor

I am unable to find the values for the Prop constant and the power factor. Is there a way I can get this information? Or an alternative way to calculate the thrust generated?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to calculate this will probably be by using the [ecalc](http://www.ecalc.ch/helicalc.php?ecalc&lang=en) helicopter calculator, they have done all these calculations for you and take into account far more factors in my experience they are very accurate. I know that most props have a Prop Constant in the 1.1 to 1.3 range, but for your specific situation according to ecalc gives a thrust to weight ratio of 2.49:1 for a 190g helicopter giving [283.1g](http://www.ecalc.ch/helicalc.php?ecalc&lang=en&cooling=medium&weight=190&calc=auw&elevation=500&airtemp=25&qnh=1013&batteries=lipo_450mah_-_65/100c&s=3&p=1&esc=0&esccont=15&escmax=20&escri=0.01&escweight=25&motor=turnigy&type=35%7Cxk2430-5800&rotor=normal&diameter=360&pitch=15.0&blades=2&rotorteeth=104&motorteeth=13&headspeed=0) of payload capacity or 473g of lift.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is very helpful and I happened to have this exact same question. BTW, recommended settings are 12º of pitch and max headspeed of 5,000 RPM. This generates a static thrust of 325g (for the 2 blade version).

Answer (score 0):

After using [ecalc](http://www.ecalc.ch/helicalc.php?ecalc&lang=en) (which is an awesome tool!) I discovered that I could approximate the results using Disk Area * RPM.

It's not useful for getting thrust in grams, but good for comparing changes in Blade size and RPM.

[image: Disk Area * RPM vs Thrust]